# lightning-input type="date" does not open date picker on focus() method

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

When the `focus()` method is called on `lightning-input type="date"`. it's not opening the date picker but its set the focus on input.
Even tried with `click()` method. 
If user clicks on input then it will open.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/SWVrVnwg/8/edit

**app.html**

```
<-- app.html -->
<template>
    <lightning-input type="date" class="date-input" label="date" ></lightning-input>
    <lightning-button label="set focus" title="Non-primary action" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
     handleClick(){
        this.template.querySelector('.date-input').focus();
        // click is not working 
        this.template.querySelector('.date-input').click();
    }
}
```

is there a known workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the [HTMLElement.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus) method. The HTMLElement.focus() method sets focus on the specified element, if it can be focused. In other word, It sets the element as the active element in the current document.

See the code below:-

```
<template>
    <lightning-input type="date" class="date-input" label="date" onfocus={handlefocus}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-button label="set focus" title="Non-primary action" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>        
</template>
```

[image]

What i have checked here is added onfocus event directly to input field. Whenever you click the button, it fires the onfocus event.

Comment: How to open input datepicker dynamically from javascript in LWC?

Comment: Does your onfocus event opens datapicker component to select date?